# POST data to php api

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am new to PHP and SQL coding and have been trying to POST data to my database, but when using Postman to check responses I get my else response and I really don't know why because my POST data is exactly what is needed.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxghi.png)

Thank you very much for helping me out!

As per request here is the code

```
<?php
    require("../database_android.php");

    if(isset($_POST["package_name"]) &&  $_POST["package_name"] != "") {
        $package_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["package_name"]);
    } else {
        echo "package_name missing";
        return;
    }

    if(isset($_POST["app_name"]) &&  $_POST["app_name"] != "") {
        $app_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["app_name"]);
    } else {
        echo "app_name missing";
        return;
    }

    if(isset($_POST["activity"]) &&  $_POST["activity"] != "") {
        $activity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["activity"]);
    } else {
        echo "activity missing";
        return;
    }

    if(isset($_POST["activity_name"]) &&  $_POST["activity_name"] != "") {
        $activity_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["activity_name"]);
    } else {
        echo "activity_name missing";
        return;
    }

    if(isset($_POST["component_info"]) &&  $_POST["component_info"] != "") {
        $component_info = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["component_info"]);
    } else {
        echo "component_info missing";
        return;
    }



    $application_id = already_exists_application($package_name);
    if($application_id < 0) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO androidactivities_application (package_name, app_name) VALUES ('". $package_name ."', '". $app_name ."')");
        $application_id = already_exists_application($package_name);
    }

    $componentinfo_id = already_exists_componentinfo($application_id, $component_info);
    if($componentinfo_id < 0 && $application_id > 0) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO androidactivities_componentinfo (application_id, activity, activity_name, component_info) VALUES ('". $application_id ."', '". $activity ."', '". $activity_name ."', '". $component_info ."')");

        echo "successful";
    } else {
        echo "exists";
    }
?>

<?php
    function already_exists_application($package_name) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from androidactivities_application WHERE package_name = '".$package_name."'");

        if($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
                return $row -> application_id;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    function already_exists_componentinfo($application_id, $component_info) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from androidactivities_componentinfo WHERE application_id = '".$application_id."' AND component_info = '".$component_info."'");

        if($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
                return $row -> componeninfo_id;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Code should be here. What does `var_dump` show? You should not be using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Code is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: P.S. Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Also, if you are running `mysql_` queries successfully, it shows you are running an unsupported version of PHP. You should upgrade your PHP version urgently to continue to receive security updates. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: Anyway, you're sending the parameters on the querystring. But for a POST request they should be in the Body.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, sorry for not posting code as I didn't thought you'd need it. I will edit it afterwards.
I used mysql library since this comes from an old GitHub post, I have tried to use newer PHP 7 but I'd need to convert all the existing code (which I tried and failed), I will only be using it locally so security is not really my concern. 
I will try what you said in your last answer and keep you updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post your data in Body tag as form data in postman. the way you are sending it gose like this ApiURL?param1=value1&param2=value2

see this image : https://pasteboard.co/JJt9RB4.png

[image]

Comment: Oh well, I feel like an idiot now! I works exactly as intended and I can see the data in my database. I'll now need to look up why it doesn't work through my android app

Comment: @Kheyonnant don't feel bad we all goes through similar situations. I am glad I help you out.. CHEERS